# Throw correct type of exception

Tags: c#, exception, architecture, parameter-passing

For example, I have a method service, which get some data from source, do something with this data and return to client of service:

```
DriverProfilerInfoDomain GetDriverProfilerInfo(int id);
```

first rows of implementation:

```
    public DriverProfilerInfoDomain GetDriverProfilerInfo(int id)
    {
        var driver = (from i in _db.Drivers
                      where i.Id == id
                      select ....)
```

but driver can be null (invalid id is passed from client part). What exception it would be better to throw? I throw `NullReferenceException` , but probably it should be like `ArgumentException` ?
From documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/best-practices-for-exceptions

> Throw an ArgumentException exception or one of the predefined classes
>   that derive from ArgumentException if invalid parameters are passed.

So, invalid id is invalid parameter. But what concrete type? `ArgumentNullException` ?

https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.argumentnullexception?view=netframework-4.7.2

> The exception that is thrown when a null reference (Nothing in Visual
>   Basic) is passed to a method that does not accept it as a valid
>   argument.

But passed parameter is not null, it's just "not found" in source...

any ideas?

Comment: Why not thrown your own custom type exception?

Comment: Similar to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121700/what-exception-should-be-thrown-when-an-ado-net-query-cannot-retrieve-the-reques

Comment: @Sach what sense to create own custom type, if MS recommends to use predefined

Comment: @OlegSh MS also recommends to avoid throwing exceptions, for example you could provide an `Exists` method which allows a client to verify the id before passing it into this method. If none of the.NET framework exceptions cover your case, you have no other option that rolling your own. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453200/exception-for-missing-data

Comment: @LennartStoop "for example you could provide an Exists method which allows a client to verify the id before passing it into this method." but then will be 2 requests to db, instead of one and code will be more complex...

Comment: Ok probably not a great example but my point is it is just a recommendation. Answers to your question will be very situational and opinionated. Personally I think it is most important to avoid a `NullReferenceException`, the exception is documented and the error message is clear and unambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

If you care about your callers you can let them know what happend by raising an ArgumentException:

```
   throw new ArgumentException($("{id} is not valid driver id."),"id");
```

You don't need a more specific type for signaling that the parameter is invalid.

The benefit of the `ArgumentException` over a `NullReferencException` is that is more clear for the caller what happend:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

which is not as meaningful as this

```
42 is not a valid driver id. Parameter name: id
```

However, in a lot of cases it is alright to simply let the `NullReferenceException` happen, no need to raise any exception on your own. When you access the null object the runtime will raise an NullReferenceException for you.

Comment: " When you access the null object the runtime will raise an NullReferenceException for you." - therefore I selected NullReferenceException. For many cases it will throw automatically by the same reason and not need to write any code...